# Error mostrar imagen BitmapFactory teniendo el path guardado kotlin/Jetpack Compose, devuelve null

Tags: kotlin, bitmap, jetpack-compose

tengo una variable String con el path absoluto de una imagen tomada por cámara pero, al transformarla en bitmap para mostrarla no funciona. He hecho varios controles de errores y he visto que es al hacer: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path) de devuelve null. El path existe y además me lo muestro por pantalla para que que sigue estando. No se si será por tamaño, peso, o el qué pero he probado varias cosas sin que funcione. La función es la siguiente:

@Composable

fun PhotoView(imagePath: String) {

```
Text(text = "Entro en PhotoView")
Text(text = imagePath)
val bitmap = remember {
    try {
        val file = File(imagePath)
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
if (bitmap != null) {
    Image(
        bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
        contentDescription = "",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(15.dp)
    )
} else {
    Text(text = "Error al cargar la imagen")
}
```

}

Alguien me puede orientar para saber cuál es el problema?
Gracias